# pngData() file save is lossy or lossless

Tags: ios, swift, lossless-compression, uiimagepngrepresentation

We are saving image as png file in swift as below

```
pngData().write(fileURL,atomic)
```

The file saved is lossy or lossless ?
I checked for any tools online but did not find answers.

Comment: I think it's neither. No data compression is performed when writing.

Comment: "PNG ...  is a raster-graphics file format that supports *lossless data compression*." [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

PNG is lossless, check the official documentation image above.